# Отредактировать виджет "Статус WooCommerce"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В WooCommerce есть такой виджет на главной странице консоли:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне хотелось бы убрать отображение закончившихся товаров и тех, которых нет в наличии, и добавить сюда отображение других статусов заказов, например, выполненных, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы убрать отображение заканчивающихся товаров и тех, что нет в наличии, добавьте в папку вашей темы файл `my-admin.css` с таким содержимым:

```
.wp-admin li.out-of-stock, .wp-admin li.low-in-stock {
    display: none;
}
```

а в functions.php своей темы такой код:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'action_admin_enqueue_scripts' );
function action_admin_enqueue_scripts( $hook_suffix ){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-admin-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/my-admin.css' );
}
```

Чтобы добавить нужную вам информацию, вставьте примерно такой код в functions.php:

```
function action_woocommerce_after_dashboard_status_widget() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_shop_orders' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $on_hold_count    = 0;
    $processing_count = 0;

    foreach ( wc_get_order_types( 'order-count' ) as $type ) {
        $counts           = (array) wp_count_posts( $type );
        $on_hold_count    += isset( $counts['wc-on-hold'] ) ? $counts['wc-on-hold'] : 0;
        $processing_count += isset( $counts['wc-processing'] ) ? $counts['wc-processing'] : 0;
    }
    ?>
    <li class="processing-orders">
        <a href="<?php echo admin_url( 'edit.php?post_status=wc-processing&post_type=shop_order' ); ?>">
            <?php
            /* translators: %s: order count */
            printf(
                _n( '<strong>%s order</strong> awaiting processing', '<strong>%s orders</strong> awaiting processing', $processing_count, 'woocommerce' ),
                $processing_count
            );
            ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="on-hold-orders">
        <a href="<?php echo admin_url( 'edit.php?post_status=wc-on-hold&post_type=shop_order' ); ?>">
            <?php
            /* translators: %s: order count */
            printf(
                _n( '<strong>%s order</strong> on-hold', '<strong>%s orders</strong> on-hold', $on_hold_count, 'woocommerce' ),
                $on_hold_count
            );
            ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_dashboard_status_widget', 'action_woocommerce_after_dashboard_status_widget' );
```

Этот код в примере выведет ту же самую строку про заказы. Вам надо исправить этот код, оставив html-разметку, но сделав вывод нужных вам величин.

Comment: Эта функция добавила вывод этой информации, но сразу после body, может я что-то сделал неправильно?

Comment: Порылся и нашел класс `WC_Admin_Dashboard` это получается нужно весь класс тогда переопределить?

Comment: нет, я специально ушел от этого. Я предложил вам решение через хук. Забыл только добавить add_action(), извиняюсь. Сейчас добавил в ответ.

Comment: Теперь все супер, спасибо большое